# Input into 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am making a Tic-tac-toe game. I've been able to achieve this in java but I am having some difficulty doing it in C++.

I have created the 2D array:

```
char board[3][3] = { { 'A', 'B', 'C' }, { 'D', 'E', 'F' }, { 'G', 'H', 'I' } };
```

Then I have the following, which is the actual gameplay. I have other functions that check the status of the game and another that displays the board for each turn. The problem I am having is when any of the players picks the cells corresponding to the first row and column. The program just ends if any of those 5 cells are selected. When the user selects the any of the other 4 cells, it correctly changes the letter to the players piece(X or O). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
while (checkStatus(player1) != true && checkStatus(player2) != true) {
    //player 1
    if (turn != false) {
        std::cout << "Player 1 Turn. Choose a Letter" << endl;
    }
    //player2
    else if(turn != true) {
        std::cout << "Player 2 Turn. Choose a Letter" << endl;
    }
    displayBoard();
    std::cin >> position;
    position = toupper(position);
    switch (position) {
    case 'A':
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
        break;
    case 'B':
        row = 0;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'C':
        row = 0;
        column = 2;
        break;
    case 'D':
        row = 1;
        column = 0;
        break;
    case 'E':
        row = 1;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'F':
        row = 1;
        column = 2;
        break;
    case 'G':
        row = 2;
        column = 0;
        break;
    case 'H':
        row = 2;
        column = 1;
        break;
    case 'I':
        row = 2;
        column = 2;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "You didn't enter a correct letter! Try again\n";
        game(player1,player2,turn);
    }
    cin.clear();
    //player X
    if (turn != false && board[row][column] != 'X' && board[row][column] != 'O') {
        board[row][column] = 'X';
        turn = false;
        checkStatus(player1);
        checkStatus(player2);
    }
    //player O
    else if (turn != true && board[row][column] != 'X' && board[row][column] != 'O') {
        board[row][column] = 'O';
        turn = true;
        checkStatus(player1);
        checkStatus(player2);
    } else {
        cout << "Choose a valid cell!";
        game(player1, player2, turn);
    }
}
```

Comment: `row = (position - 'A') / 3; column = (position - 'A') % 3;`

Comment: Maybe not related to your problem, but I'm assuming the code you show is in the `game` function, In that case, what if some illegal input is entered? You call the `game` function recursively,  When the recursive call returns you will have some troubles as the original function will resume just where the call left off which is with the assumption that the input was correct and you will most likely end up with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Instead I suggest you use a loop, and if the incorrect input was given you continue the loop, else exit the loop.

Comment: I tried doing this and I keep getting the same problem. What is this suppose to do?Thanks again.